# Jammit compression works in dev mode, but not as compressed JS

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-plugins, jammit

My Rails app is fairly progressed now, and I want to compress the included JS files (Aloha Editor with plugins + Gritter, making up multiple files with over 1MB of JS) properly. I have decided for Jammit, because of its fine Rails integration. Here is my config/assets.yml:

```
package_assets:          always
javascript_compressor:   closure
compressor_options:
  compilation_level: ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS

javascripts:
  admin:
    - public/aloha/aloha.js
    - public/aloha/plugins/com.gentics.aloha.plugins.Format/plugin.js
    - public/aloha/plugins/com.gentics.aloha.plugins.Table/plugin.js
    - public/aloha/plugins/com.gentics.aloha.plugins.List/plugin.js
    - public/aloha/plugins/com.gentics.aloha.plugins.Link/plugin.js
    - public/javascripts/*.js
    - public/javascripts/gritter/*.js
```

For explanation: aloha.js is an extended jQuery 1.4.2 lib, and the files in /javascripts/*.js and /gritter/*.js are mostly dependent on it (jQuery).
I am including the tags in my view code with

```
<%= include_javascripts :admin %>
```

straightforward.

When switched to dev mode (assets.yml has package_assets: on), Jammit leaves the JS files alone and embeds all of them, one by one, and my app is just fine.

However, when in production mode (env = :production, or assets.yml has package_assets: always), Jammit creates a compressed JS file of roughly 700kB (wow, that's a fat monster) which embeds correctly, but I get a JS error "**jQuery is not defined**" on page load. My first guess would be that the order of JS files is changed during compilation, even though it should not?

One more thing: Leaving the compressor at default (yui) causes even worse JS errors on loading.

Can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 2):

We've had a lot of issues compressing Aloha Editor with compilers that do "advanced optimisations" - aloha core compiles fine, but the ExtJS dependency fails the compile.

As `aloha.js` is already compiled, see if it can skip compilation and just be concatenated to the result file instead of compiled again.

Another thing to try is see if you can enable just the `whitespace_only` option in your compiler or `basic_optimisations`. This will show whether or not it is an issue with the compilation process or not.

Answer (score 0):

The order of the files is likely the issue. I would recommend specify each file explicitly and in the order you want them in (ie. do not do /*.js).

If this works for you, then you could move some of the javascript files that don't require an order into subfolders and call /*.js on that subfolder.